# Splitting text in PHP

Tags: php, regex, text, split

I want to know is there any way to split text like this:

123456789 into 123-456-789

as to add "-" after every 3 characters?

Just wanted to know, as I know the reverse, but how to do this is over my head. ;)

and also if the text is

```
ABCDEFGHI OR A1B2C3D4E or any other format 
without any space between the characters !
```

language: PHP only

Comment: Yes, this is certainly possible. Give us a clue, though... what programming language are you using?

Comment: This will certainly be possible, but you'll get better responses if you indicate what language or platform you're working in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
$i = '123456789';
echo 'result: ', wordwrap($i, 3, '-', true);
```

prints

```
result: 123-456-789
```

see http://php.net/wordwrap

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a big fan of regexes for simple string extraction (especially fixed length extractions), preferring them for slightly more complex stuff. Almost every language has a substring function so, presuming your input has already been validated, a simple (pseudo-code since you haven't specified a language):

```
s = substring (s,0,3) + "-" + substring (s,3,3) + "-" + substring (s,6,3)
```

If you want it every three characters for a variable length string (with odd size at the end):

```
t = ""
sep = ""
while s != "":
    if s.len <= 3:
        t = t + sep + s
        s = ""
    else:
        t = t + sep + substring (s,0,3)
        s = substring (s,3)
    sep = "-"
s = t
```

Comment: but what about ABCDEFGHI

OR A1B2C3D4E

Comment: What about it? If the spec is to handle any string, the above code will handle any string. It doesn't have to be numeric.

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of completeness, here is a Python solution:

```
>>> a = "123456789"
>>> a[0:3] + "-" + a[3:6] + "-" + a[6:9]
'123-456-789'
```

Since you updated your question to specify a PHP solution, this should work:

```
substr($a, 0, 3) . "-" . substr($a, 3, 3) . "-" . substr($a, 6, 3)
```

See [`substr`](http://nz.php.net/substr) for more information on this function. This will work not only for digits, but for alphabetic characters too.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this can be sanely done in a regex with lookahead:

```
s/(.{3})(?=.)/$1-/g
```

Since you mentioned PHP in a comment:

```
preg_replace ("/(.{3})(?=.)/", "$1-", $string);
```

*edit*:  After VolkerK showed `wordwrap`, I found `chunk-split` in the documentation:

```
$new_string = chunk_split ($string, 3, '-');
```

This has the advantage that it also works when there are spaces in the string (wordwrap would prefer to break at the spaces).

Comment: Your definition of sane is at odds with mine :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yet another Python version:

```
>>> x="123456789"
>>> out=[x[i:i+3] for i in xrange(0, len(x), 3)]
>>> print "-".join(out)
123-456-789
```

Answer (score 1):

For any language:

- Create an empty string variable called "result"
- Create an integer counter variable, "i", which increments until the length of the *original* string (the one with the number)
- Append each character from the original string to "result"
- If i modulo 3 (usually % or mod) is zero, append a dash to "result"

Answer (score 0):

In Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "123456789";
$string =~ /(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d+)/;

print "$1-$2-$3"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with (among other means) a regular expression match and replace. The exact syntax depends on the tool or programming language you are using. For instance, one way to do it in Perl would be

```
$a = "123456789";
$a =~ s/(\d{3})/$1-/g;
chop($a);
print $a;
```

Line 2 replaces every 3 digits for the same 3 digits and a dash. With chop() we delete the trailing dash.

There is another question here. What to do when the string doesn't contain a multiple by 3 amount of digits? If such strings were allowed, then the above snippet would need modification.

Also, depending on the specifics of the case, you might get away with simple substring replacement, or string slicing.

Comment: This seems to chop off a digit if the number of digits is not a multiple of 3.

Comment: what if its ABCDEFGHI OR A1B2C3D4E 

then how to split the text and in php only

Comment: Heh, no, I seem to have stopped at the chop.

Answer (score 0):

One more Perl example. This doesn't remove final groups smaller than three, and it leaves initial groups of less than three digits alone. It's based (pretty shamelessly) on the "money numbers" example in *Learning Perl* (page 212 of the 5th ed):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Gimme' a number: ";
chomp(my $number = <STDIN>);

1 while ($number =~ s/([0-9]{3})([0-9]+)/$1-$2/);

print "Now it's $number\n";
```